# How to check if printing to file

Tags: fltk

Is there a way to tell if Fl_Printer is printing to file (.ps file)? My app needs to know if the user has chosen to print to file, so it can add some extra stuff to the printed page. I have looked at the documentation of Fl_Printer and all its heritage lineage to no avail. Is this possible with the current API? My app uses FLTK 1.3.3 and is built for Linux and OS X.

**Edit**

```
#include <FL/Fl_Printer.H>
...
void SWindow::on_print()
{
    Fl_Printer printer;
    if( printer.start_job(1) ) return;
    if( printer.start_page() ) return;
    // Drawing takes place here
    printer.end_page();
    printer.end_job();
}
```

Comment: So if the user prints to the printer, they get one lot of info.  If they print to a file and then print that file they get additional info?  You're going to get users asking why they don't have the extra information.  Why not just add the extra information regardless of how it is printed?

Comment: The difference between printing to paper or file is not what's important here. This is the way the customer wants it and they have good reasons for this. The key technical issue is to determine if the user has selected to print to file. I'll take it from there.

Comment: Can you post your FL_Printer/FL_Postscript call.  I just want to see how you're calling it.  You may be able to derive a version that knows what it is printing to.

Comment: Here is a snippet with the relevant calls to Fl_Printer
<CODE>
#include <FL/Fl_Printer.H>
...
void SWindow::on_print()
{
    Fl_Printer printer;
    if( printer.start_job(1) ) return;
    if( printer.start_page() ) return;
    // Drawing takes place here
    printer.end_page();
    printer.end_job();
}
</CODE>
The printing works very well. There is nothing to it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an elegant method but it will work.

1. Modify Fl_Printer.H.  In class Fl_Printer, change private to public
2. Modify Fl_PostScript.H.  In class Fl_PostScript_File_Device, change protected to public
3. There is no need to rebuild the libraries since the headers only affect compilation.  You can change headers without having to change libraries.

In your code

```
if (printer.printer->driver()->ps_filename_ == NULL)
{
     // printing to printer
 }
 else
 {
     // printing to file
 }
```

Comment: Thanks cup, That's a good observation and I agree with you about not being very elegant, but it gets the job done. This is one of those cases when you wish the base class data members were not private. If they were protected instead, I could derive a new class from Fl_Printer and expose the added functionality.

Comment: I hardly use private: almost always use protected in case I need to write an introspective class for debugging.